# Append does not update list values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to find the rolling mean of the last 10 elements in a list in Python, using something like:

```
            ...
            mean_last_10 =  stats.mean(data_list[i-10:i])
            print("test mean", mean_last_10 )

                array.append([id[i],a[i], mean_last_10])
```

The printed values look correct but the `array` shows that values for `mean_last_10` is kept the same. Why is this the case? Should I use `deepcopy`?

Comment: is `df` a list or a dataframe?

Comment: @BurningAlcohol sorry it is an array. I've changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside your for loop create a `list`

```
mean_last_10 = []


        mean_last_10.append(stats.mean(data_list[i-10:i]))
        array.append([id[i],a[i], mean_last_10[i]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This may be a careless mistake, should I delete the question?

Comment: @nilsinelabore no worry keep it as it:-), I will vote for u ~ if you worry about the downvote ~